# What is the plural of a

Tags: grammaticality, numbers

What is the plural of word "a" ..can we. Say, we have spent a beautiful night with friends for three days.

Comment: I think a is not a part of Part of speech.. It's a definite article.. Perhaps, am l right?

Comment: Its part of speech is 'article'. Indefinite, not definite (_the_ is definite). However, the indefinite article has no plural, and _a/an_ is only used before singular count nouns.

Comment: A dog is a good companion. Dogs are good companions.  One might argue that with count nouns, if you don't use a/an, you might use the s morpheme.

Comment: Unlike French, English doesn't use particular articles to indicate whether nouns are plural or singular. In French, singular articles are **le** and **la**. The plural article is **les**. This question would probably be more appropriate for the English Language Learners Stack Exchange. http://www.frenchtutorial.com/en/learn-french/basics/le_la_les

Comment: Why bring another language  into it when the OP is having difficulties with English??

Answer (score 2):

There is no plural indefinite article in English. You simply avoid the article. Hence: we have spent beautiful nights.  For further reference: [Why is there no plural indefinite article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/why-is-there-no-plural-indefinite-article)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although this doesn't help you, I would argue that while there is no exact grammatical plural of *a*, words like *many* and *several* serve a similar purpose.

> I had a beautiful night. [singular]
>   I had several beautiful nights. [plural]

But you need a different type of construction—one that uses a specific number. I can think of a couple of possibilities.

> We spent three beautiful nights with friends.
>   For three days in a row, we spent a beautiful night with friends.

I think the first is a more common way of expressing what you want. The second may sound a bit odd, but it's understandable and not wrong.